# Finding the impulse response of a system from its step response

Tags: integration, derivatives, dirac-delta, step-function

We know the impulse response and the step response have the following relationship:
$$h(t) = \frac{dy_{step}}{dt} $$

Given the following step response of a system:

$$ y_{step(t)} = 
\begin{cases}
 0, \quad t\leq 0 \\
 t, \quad 0\leq t \leq 1 \\
 1, \quad t\ge 1.
\end{cases}
$$

If I write out the step function using $u(t)$, then $y_{step(t)} = t*u(t) - t*u(t - 1)$.

Question 1: did I write out the function correctly?

Assuming it is, I proceed to take the derivative:
$$h(t)=\frac{dy_{step(t)}}{dt} = \frac{d(t*u(t) - t*u(t - 1))}{dt}$$
$$ = u(t) + t\cdot\delta(t)-u(t-1)-t\cdot\delta(t-1)$$

Question 2: did I come up with the correct derivative?

Question 3: assume yes to Question 2, I know $t\cdot\delta(t)=0 \forall t$, but how do I deal with $t\cdot\delta(t-1)$?

p.s., the book answer show the $h(t) = u(t) - u(t-1)$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use images of text instead of the text itself. It is exclusive of some users and is not the intended purpose of the image tooling.

Comment: @Nij, here, it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: no
Q2: no
Q3: suggests avoiding this approach

Let's try to sort things out:

indeed, in control theory there is a connection between step and impulse responses, however, due to the fact that we are dealing with distributions and not functions, this formula must be approached with caution (note that $y_{step}(t)$ is not differentiable in 0 and 1).

Lets define Heaviside Unit Step Function as
$$
u(t-c)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{for} \ t<c\\
1 & \text{for} \ t\geq c\\        
\end{cases}
$$
For the step response you presented it is
$$
y_{step}(t)=t\cdot u(t)-(t-1)\cdot u(t-1)
$$
so let's check
$$
y_{step}(t)=
\begin{cases}
t<0 & 0 + 0 = 0\\
0< t<1 & t-0=t\\
1< t & t-(t-1)=1\\        
\end{cases}
$$
this is a typical task for using the Laplace transform
| Time domain   | s domain (Laplace transform) |
|:-------------:|:----------------------------:|
| $f'(t)$       | $sF(s)$                      |
| 1             | $\frac{1}{s}$                |
| t             | $\frac{1}{s^2}$              |
| $f(t-a)u(t-a)$| $e^{-as}F(s)$                |
so in s domain:
$$
F_{step}(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}
$$
$$
F_{impulse}(s)=F_{step}(s)s=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{e^{-s}}{s}
$$
so
$$
F_{impulse}(t)=u(t)-u(t-1)
$$
in the time domain can be written in detail
$$
F_{impulse}(t)=\frac{dy_{step}(t)}{dt}=
\begin{cases}
t<0 & (0)'=0 \\
0< t<1 & (t)'=1\\
1< t & (1)'=0\\        
\end{cases}
$$
which can be written as
$$
F_{impulse}(t)=u(t)-u(t-1)
$$